# Setting Y coordinate of System.Windows.Point from a list gives modify error

Tags: c#

I am having some trouble setting the Y Coordinate of a Point when I am accessing the Point from a list.

For example, this works.

```
System.Windows.Point test = new System.Windows.Point(6,5);
test.Y = 6;
```

However, if I have a list of points and I access a point via the list to set the Y coordinate, I am getting an error.

```
List<System.Windows.Point> bfunction = new List<System.Windows.Point>();
bfunction.Add(new System.Windows.Point(0, 1));
bfunction[0].Y = 6;
```

The bfunction[0] is underlined and gives me an error of "Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.List.this[int]' because it is not a variable."

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is stopping you from making a mistake, basically. When you access `bfunction[0]` that will return a *copy* of the point. `Point` is, unfortunately (IMO) a mutable struct. So if the compiler allowed you to change the copy, that copy would then just be thrown away and the statement would have been pointless. Instead, you need to use a variable to take the copy, change it there, then put it back in the list:

```
Point point = bfunction[0];
point.Y = 6;
bfunction[0] = point;
```

This wouldn't be necessary if `Point` were a reference type, and you wouldn't have had the opportunity to make the error if `Point` had been an *immutable* value type instead. You'd still have needed to separately fetch and set, but it would have been something like:

```
bfunction[0] = bfunction[0].WithY(6);
```

... where `WithY` would have returned a `Point` value which had the same `X` value as the original, but the specified `Y`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I appreciate the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, thank you for your reply.

here is my solution:

```
if (reset == false && run == true)

{
  for ( int i = 0;i < locations.Count;i++)

  {
    double stepX = rnd.Next(-1, 2) * 5 * rnd.NextDouble();
    double stepY = rnd.Next(-1, 2) * 5 * rnd.NextDouble();
    double stepZ = rnd.Next(-1, 2) * 5 * rnd.NextDouble();
    Vector3d transform = new Vector3d(stepX, stepY, stepZ);

    locations[i] += transform;

    // Constrain points to boundary conditions

    Point3d ptx = locations[i]; // make temp variable to hold all points
    ptx.X = CV.Constrain(ptx.X, 0, bX - 1); // access X coordinates and modify them
    locations[i] = ptx; // assign new X coordinates to points in List

    Point3d pty = locations[i];
    pty.Y = CV.Constrain(pty.Y, 0, bY - 1);
    locations[i] = pty;

    Point3d ptz = locations[i];
    ptz.Z = CV.Constrain(ptz.Z, 0, bZ - 1);
    locations[i] = ptz;





    Component.ExpireSolution(true);

  }

}
```