# How to change a Point struct property while its in a List?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++ )
{
    list.Add(new Point(i, 3));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    list[i].X = 100;
}

Point point = new Point(0, 1);
point.X = 1;
point.Y = 10;
```

When I try to change X or Y property of a newly created Point structure there is no problem:

```
Point point = new Point(0, 1);
point.X = 1;
point.Y = 10;
```

But when I'm trying to do the same in a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    list[i].X = 100;
}
```

The compiler is telling me

> Cannot modify the return value of
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Point>.this[int]`
>   because it is not a variable

Can anybody please explain me this.

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526/changing-the-value-of-an-element-in-a-list-of-structs) for a thorough explanation, but basically and simplified: by calling `list[i]` you get a copy of the list item at index `i`. The compiler prevents you from doing useless things, as `list[i].X = 100;` wouldn't really do anything (apart from modifying a copy that would go out of scope immediately).

Comment: Thank You, but is there some workaround to this?  In a duplicate they are using interface but at the same time they are talking about custom structure. And I'm bind to Point structure. And I cannot just do it like this: list[i] = new Point(100,0)

Comment: Why can't you just do that? It's how you should do it. When modifying a struct list, you have to re-assign the item (`list[i] = new Point(100, 0)`).

Comment: I would say, [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222757/setting-y-coordinate-of-system-windows-point-from-a-list-gives-modify-error) will be a better solution for your problem.

Comment: Because of performance issues. I struggle to avoid creating new instances of Point structures because its a bottleneck of my program.